# Plotly legends overlapping on top of the chart

Tags: angularjs, charts, plotly.js

By using plotly, I am creating my analytics dashboard which has pie, bar and different kind of charts. I have a pie chart which has huge data and legends nearly more than 60. It's rendering properly in browser(bigger screen) problem is with the mobile screens. Chart legends are overlapping the actual chart.I am expecting to show chart as like below in mobile screens. Can anyone help me on this.

[image]

My Json looks like below.

```
{
  "data": [{
    "values": [1058,177,75,53,28,23,15,8,7,6,5,5,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    "labels": ["Vision Corporation","Corporate Human Resources","Human Resources-West","Human Resources-East","Human Resources-Central","Recruiting-East","Human Resources","Recruiting-South","Payroll","Recruiting-West","Human Resources-South","Recruiting-Central","200-Human Resources","Direction des Ressources Humaines","Accounts Payable","Commercial Sales","Commercial Sales-West","Services-East","Vision Australia","Vision Industries","Others"],
    "type": "pie",
    "textposition":"inside"
  }],
  "linked": {
    "layout": {
      "legend":{
        "orientation": "h",
        "x": 1.02,
        "xanchor": "center",
        "y": 1.0,
        "yanchor": "bottom"
      },
      "margin":{
        "l": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: have not tried this on mobile. However, I had a similar issue on the browser (huge legend) - and the following did solve the issue:

You can control the size of the chart. By increasing the height property, you will leave more room for your legend.

Add a 'height' property under the 'layout' object, and play with the sizing to fit your data -

```
"layout": {
  "height": 1000, ...
```

You can also add a width property if needed. See an example [here](https://plot.ly/python/setting-graph-size/) (not in JSON, but the properties are clear).